# How to make sure Aether 'downloads' all dependencies in your local repo?

Tags: maven, dependencies, artifacts, aether

I am trying to resolve direct dependencies for a project, basically the run time and compile time dependencies in its POM and also the transitives. For this I have the following code

```
public class GetDirectDependencies
{

public static void main( String[] args )
    throws Exception
{
    System.out.println( "------------------------------------------------------------" );
    System.out.println( GetDirectDependencies.class.getSimpleName() );

    RepositorySystem system = Booter.newRepositorySystem();

    RepositorySystemSession session = Booter.newRepositorySystemSession( system );

    Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact( "org.eclipse.aether:aether-impl:1.0.0.v20140518" );

    ArtifactDescriptorRequest descriptorRequest = new ArtifactDescriptorRequest();
    descriptorRequest.setArtifact( artifact );
    descriptorRequest.setRepositories( Booter.newRepositories( system, session ) );

    ArtifactDescriptorResult descriptorResult = system.readArtifactDescriptor( session, descriptorRequest );

    for ( Dependency dependency : descriptorResult.getDependencies() )
    {
        System.out.println( dependency );
    }
}
```

}

This works correctly but how do I get a 'resolved ' list of dependencies. I need to be able to download this resolved artifact in my local repo. Basically I need a List to return from which I can get to the jar on the local disk.

Comment: Why not using Maven itself which already downloads all needed artifacts?

Comment: I am trying to resolve all direct and transitive dependencies for a pom

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. Maven already does that. What is the purpose of doing it via Java code instaed of using Maven itself?

Comment: does maven resolve all dependencies it into a single jar?

Comment: You would like to create a jar-with-dependencies or ueberjar/fatjar ? If so this can be achieved by maven-assembly-plugin or maven-shade-plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the jar file and the physical path to that jar you should 'resolve' it. I achieved it in the following way :

```
Artifact artifact = new DefaultArtifact( "org.eclipse.aether:aether-util:1.0.0.v20140518" );

    ArtifactRequest artifactRequest = new ArtifactRequest();
    artifactRequest.setArtifact( artifact );
    artifactRequest.setRepositories( Booter.newRepositories( system, session ) );

    ArtifactResult artifactResult = system.resolveArtifact( session, artifactRequest );

    artifact = artifactResult.getArtifact();
To get the file:
    artifact.getFile();
```